# Configure web.config for Redirecting/Forwarding an URL with specific pattern to another pattern (with colon and double slash)

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I have an old database, which returns hughe texts with links to non-existent URLs in the ASP.NET application. The links are looking like this:

http://bbmag295:7777/$element://%7B57980C01-3974-49e5-91D4-49B843359557%7D

And should be transformed to this:

http://bbmag295:7777/ShowGlossary.aspx?id=57980C01-3974-49e5-91D4-49B843359557

That means the pattern between "$element://%7B" and "%7D" should be picked and redirected to ShowGlossary.aspx?id=...

I have written the following RegMatch-Expression in C# for this:

```
    string pattern2 = @"(element://{[^>]+})";

    MatchCollection matches2 = Regex.Matches(neuerString, pattern2);

    if (matches2.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (Match m in matches2)
        {
            string toReplace = "$" + m.Groups[1].ToString();
            string guid = toReplace.ToString().Replace("$element://", "");

            neuerString = neuerString.Replace(toReplace, "ShowGlossary.aspx?id=" + guid); 

        }
    }
```

I just tried this in the Web.Config but i cannot get the match url to work:

```
              <rewrite>
                <rules>
                  <rule name="Query String Rewrite">  
                    <!--<match url="(element://{[^>]+})" />-->
                    <!--<match url="^Article/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />-->
                    <!--<action type="Rewrite" url="ShowGlossary.aspx?ID={R:1}"/>  -->
                    <!--<match url="^Article/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />-->
                    <match url="^\$element://([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="ShowGlossary.aspx?id={R:1}" />
                  </rule>      
                </rules>
              </rewrite>
```

Is it possible that the :// Part makes it impossible to make such a forwarding? The colon (:) leads to an error as "potential dangerous request". What can id do?

Finally i got it to work with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
  <security> 
       <requestFiltering allowHighBitCharacters="true" allowDoubleEscaping="true" /> 
  </security>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Query String Rewrite">  
        <match url="^\$element:/\{([_0-9a-z-]+)\}" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="ShowGlossary.aspx?id={R:1}" />
      </rule>      
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="EAPFile" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=~MDB/plm.eap" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="plmConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestPathInvalidCharacters=""/>
      <pages validateRequest="false" />
    </system.web>
    <system.web.extensions>
      <scripting>
        <webServices>
          <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
        </webServices>
      </scripting>
    </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

1.) Set requestPathInvalidCharacters to "" 
2.) 
3.)

My next problem is, that after rewrite the styles are not loaded :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got it to work using redirect instead of rewrite.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
  <security> 
       <requestFiltering allowHighBitCharacters="true" allowDoubleEscaping="true" /> 
  </security>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Query String Rewrite">  
        <match url="^\$element:/\{([_0-9a-z-]+)\}" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="ShowGlossary.aspx?id={R:1}" />
      </rule>      
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="EAPFile" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=~MDB/plm.eap" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="plmConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestPathInvalidCharacters=""/>
      <pages validateRequest="false" />
    </system.web>
    <system.web.extensions>
      <scripting>
        <webServices>
          <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
        </webServices>
      </scripting>
    </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

After that i had to download the rewrite module otherwise i got Error 500 in IIS (in Visual Studio it already worked the whole time)